# Passing Parameters using jetty contextHandler

Tags: jetty

I'm wanting to make some custom endpoints that point to another endpoint in my jetty setup. For example, I already have and endpoint like http://myserver.com/app that serves up a help page. Further, if I pass certain arguments, I get different pages. So for example http://myserver.com/app?app_id=56 might serve one app and http://myserver.com/app?app_id=48 might serve a static html page that documents functions.

For the sake of some of the users, I'd like to set up simple endpoints for a few of the commonly used apps. So if a user went to http://myserver.com/docs, they'd should see the same thing as http://myserver.com/app?app_id=48.

I've been trying to accomplish this with .xml Configuration files. So far I've got it almost working.

```
<?xml version="1.0"  encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Mort Bay Consulting//DTD Configure//EN" "http://jetty.eclipse.org/configure.dtd">

<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler">
  <Set name="contextPath">/docs</Set>
  <Set name="resourceBase">http://localhost:8080</Set>
  <Set name="handler">
    <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ResourceHandler">
      <Set name="welcomeFiles">
        <Array type="String">
          <Item>app</Item>
        </Array>
      </Set>
      <Set name="cacheControl">max-age=3600,public</Set>
    </New>
  </Set>
</Configure>
```

Using this config file going to /docs serves the aforementioned help page which I would normally see by loading http://myserver.com/app, my hangup is I can't figure out how to pass the appropriate app_id.

I think I may end up creating some sort of custom handler but I'm not exactly sure how to go about implementing it.

And just to complicate the issue, I also want to be able to pass some arbitrary parameter to my endpoint and have it passed along. So http://myserver.com/docs?foo=bar would display http://myserver.com/app?app_id=48&foo=bar.

Should I be going about this another way or can this all be accomplished through the config xml files?

Answer (score 1):

If using Jetty 9.2+ you can just use the built-in static resource serving (magic provided by the `deploy` module)

Eg:

```
$ cd /path/to/my.base
$ ls -l webapps
total 4
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 joakim joakim 84 Oct 27 17:24 docs -> /opt/my/docs
$ java -jar /path/to/jetty-dist/start.jar
```

But if you really want to handle static resources with an XML ...

- Don't use `ContextHandler` and `ResourceHandler` they are only for the most simplistic and naive of file serving scenarios.
- Use an anonymous `WebAppContext`
- Set `resourceBase` to the directory where your documents are

Here's how you setup a static file serving XML (done right)

```
$ cd /path/to/my.base
$ cat webapps/docs.xml 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure_9_3.dtd">
<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
  <Set name="contextPath">/docs</Set>
  <Set name="resourceBase">/opt/my/docs</Set>
  <Set name="defaultsDescriptor"><Property name="jetty.base" default="."/>/etc/docs-web.xml</Set>
</Configure>

$ cat etc/docs-web.xml 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app 
   xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
   metadata-complete="false"
   version="3.1">

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>aliases</param-name>
      <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>acceptRanges</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>dirAllowed</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>welcomeServlets</param-name>
      <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>redirectWelcome</param-name>
      <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>maxCacheSize</param-name>
      <param-value>256000000</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>maxCachedFileSize</param-name>
      <param-value>200000000</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>maxCachedFiles</param-name>
      <param-value>2048</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>gzip</param-name>
      <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>etags</param-name>
      <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>useFileMappedBuffer</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>cacheControl</param-name>
      <param-value>max-age=3600,public</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
$ java -jar /path/to/jetty-dist/start.jar
```

Comment: Thanks I'll give this a go.